Estimating the number of states of a simple Markov chain
We have a Markov chain with $n$ states. If the chain is in any of the states, $i$, there is a $\frac{1}{n-1}$ chance of it transitioning to any of the other $n-1$ states. We don't know what $n$ is. We start the chain in some random state, and make a bunch of transitions. We do have the ability to recognize an old state we visited if we transition to it again. As we transition, we keep track of the number of times we visit each state we see in an array.
For example, after $10$ transitions, our array, $a_{10}$ might look like: $[4, 3, 3]$. This would mean that one of the states was seen four times, and two other states were visited $3$ times so far.
Given the array, $a_k$ after $k$ transitions, we'd like to establish confidence bounds on $n$. How do we go about this?

Side note: I'm hoping to eventually evolve this and use it to establish bounds on the number of 2-d meshes of a 4-d cube: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428499/how-many-ways-to-flatten-a-tesseract-onto-a-table

Since your Markov chain has equal probability for all states, isn't this functionally equivalent to parameter estimation for a discrete uniform distribution? You should be able to get estimates or confidence intervals based on the max order statistic. If you want to do these estimates in practice, you probably want to use something like the HyperLogLog algorithm.

Not a complete answer but one cumbersome way of doing it is the following:
Let $S_k$ denote the number of distinct states visited until $k-1$ transitions. Your objective is to find the distribution of $S_k$ in terms of $n$. Easy to see that
$$S_{k+1} = S_k+Y_k~, \quad Y_k|S_k \sim \text{Bern}\Big(\frac{n-S_k}{n-1}\Big)~,\quad k \ge 2~,$$
and $S_2 \equiv 2$.
Denoting $p_{k,j}:=\mathsf{P}(S_k=j)$, we have
$$p_{k+1,j} = p_{k,j} \frac{j-1}{n-1} + p_{k,j-1} \frac{n-j+1}{n-1}~,\quad k \ge 2,~ j \ge2$$
with the boundary conditions (i) $p_{k,1} = 0$ for $k \ge 2$ (ii) $p_{2,2} = 1$ and (iii) $p_{k,j} = 0$ for $j>\min(n,k).$
Now I have not solved the recurrence relation but it is doable, at least in principle.
Edit: How to use to get confidence interval
Denoting $m_k:=\mathsf{E}(S_k)$,
$$m_{k+1} = m_k+\frac{n-m_k}{n-1}, \quad k \ge 2$$
and $m_2 = 2$. Solving the recurrence, we find for $k\ge2$
$$m_k = n-\frac{(n-2)^{k-1}}{(n-1)^{k-2}}~.$$
Next one can calculate the variance of $S_k$ using $p_{k,j}$'s or by directly obtaining a recurrence relation and solving it. The recurrence relation is as follows:
$$\mathsf{E}(S_{k+1}^2) = \mathsf{E}(S_{k}^2)+\mathsf{E}(Y_{k}^2)+2\mathsf{E}(S_{k}Y_{k})~,$$
where the last two quantities can be obtained after conditioning on $S_k$. Let us denote $\text{Var}(S_k) = \sigma^2_k$. Then using CLT,
$$\frac{\bar{S}_k-m_k}{\sigma_k/\sqrt{m}} \implies N(0,1)~,$$
where $\bar{S}_k$ is the sample average of $S_k$'s over $m$ repetitions (of your experiments).
Now this can be used to construct a confidence interval: observe that $m_k$ and $\sigma_k$ are functions of $n$. You can thus back-calculate (e.g., using Newton-Raphson) what values of $n$ would keep $\sqrt{m}(\bar{S}_k-m_k)/\sigma_k$ between $-1.96$ and $1.96$ (for $95\%$ confidence interval).
A better approach:
I was not able to solve this but a better approach would be to construct a confidence interval of the form $[S_k, S_k+c]$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$. Now $\mathsf{P}(n \in [S_k, S_k+c]) = \mathsf{P}(S_k>n-c)$ and thus involves computing the tail of distribution of $S_k$.
This can be done using the $p_{k,j}$'s. Since $n$ is unknown, the next step is to obtain an upper bound for this tail probability using your sample statistic(s). However, I was not able to find this as the tail probability is increasing in $n$.

What is $Y_k$? You never defined it.

Sorry it was only implicit. $Y_k$ is the indicator variable taking value $1$ iff a new state is visited on $(k-1)$-th transition. I previously defined $S_k$ as the number of distinct states until $k$ transitions. It should be $(k-1)$. Will change it.

I see. Thanks. This is a good answer and takes me beyond where I was. However, you don't seem to be taking into account the counts of the states. Also, if we found $p_{k,j}$,  its unclear how we would use it to get confidence intervals.

I have now included the construction of the confidence interval.

The available data (full number of ocurrences of each visited state) seems more informative, it's not evident to me that restricting to $S_k$ (number of visited states) is the optimal thing to do.

@leonbloy Agreed, not claimed to be optimal. As mentioned, possibly there are even better approaches only involving $S_k$ than the one presented.

Following Sounak's answer. Letting $S_k$ be the total number of distinct states visited after $k$ iterations [*], and $p_{k,j}=P(S_k = j)$, we get the recursion
$$p_{k,j} = \frac{1}{n-1} \left[ (j-1) p_{k-1,j}  + (n+1-j) p_{k-1,j-1}  \right]$$
with the initial condition $p_{2,j} = \delta_{j-2} = [0,1,0, 0 \cdots]$
The solution is
$$p_{k,j} = S_{k-1,j-1} \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-j)! (n-1)^{k-2}} \tag 1$$
where $S$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.
An example for $n=10$ is shown below.
The form of $(1)$ is not very amenable of algebraic manipulation. But in our sceneario, $n$ is the parameter to be estimated and $j$ is the observed random data ($k$ is fixed). Hence, for example, in a Maximum Likelihood setting, the Stirling number is irrelevant.
We also should stipulate if we are estimating over a single observation (a single chain sequence) or several.
If we have a single realization, then a candidate estimation could be $\hat n = \lceil n_0 \rceil$ where $n_0$ is the root of
$$ (1- 1/n)^{k-2} = 1- \frac{j-2}{n-1}$$
We can also compute the loglikelihood if we have several realizations, or we can plug $(1)$ into some Bayesian estimation procedure. In any case, it seems that numerical computation is inevitable.
Edit: Here I add the result of some simulations. I take $n=30$ and several values of $k$, and I plot the log likelihood (from $(1)$, without including the irrelevant Stirling number) as a function of the (assumed as unknown) $n$. As expected, the maximum is near the true value of $n$, even when $k$ is a small fraction of $n$, but in this case (last graph) we need to take a large sample (300 runs).





A table of values of $(1)$, for $n=10$.

[*] This is not necessarily the best approach, it remains to be seen if $S_k$ is a sufficient statistic; I suspect it is.

Python code:
import math
import numpy as np

## parameters of simulation
n = 30  # different elements
k = 10  # length of sequence (time)
samples = 300  # repetitions of each sequence try

print(f"starting simulation n={n} k={k} samples={samples}")
###################################

rng = np.random.default_rng()


# produces one sample (one sequence)
def producej(n, k):
    app = {}
    xs = rng.integers(0, n - 1, k)
    v = xs[0]
    app[v] = 1
    for i in range(1, k):
        v = xs[i] if xs[i] < v else xs[i] + 1
        app[v] = 1
    j = len(app.keys())
    return j


########################################
ac = 0
lh = np.zeros(n + 21)
lh[0] = lh[1] = lh[2] = np.nan
for _ in range(samples):
    j = producej(n, k)
    for nx in range(3, len(lh)):
        if nx < j:
            lh[nx] = np.nan
        elif not np.isnan(lh[nx]):
            lh[nx] += math.log(math.factorial(nx - 2)) - (
                math.log(math.factorial(nx - j)) + (k - 2) * math.log(nx - 1)
            )

# print results, normalized
for i in range(len(lh)):
    if not np.isnan(lh[i]):
        print(f"{i}\t{(lh[i]/samples):.7f}")


Thanks! Can you please share the code you used to create those graphs and data? Perhaps in a Github gist?

I added the Python code
